# Prevent BS4 to add duplicate tags

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm appending HTML snippet/elements to existing an HTML and BS4 duplicates the element(s) inside it. How to prevent it?

**Simplified code**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs4
html = bs4("<!DOCTYPE html>", "html5lib")
message =  bs4("<span>Complete all required fields.<span>", "html.parser")
html.select("body")[0].append(message)
print(html.prettify())
```

**Output**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
  <span>
   Complete all required fields.
   <span>
   </span>
  </span>
 </body>
</html>
```

**Expected**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
  <span>
   Complete all required fields.
  </span>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did it all right, but you forgot to close the span

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs4
html = bs4("<!DOCTYPE html>", "html5lib")
message =  bs4("<span>Complete all required fields.</span>", "html.parser")#changed
html.select("body")[0].append(message)
print(html.prettify())

o/p:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
<span>
 Complete all required fields.
</span>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Jai! That took hours from me. The actual code isn't really like that but that's the straightforward code, forgot to add slash in the element builder during concatenation.

Comment: Welcome!!..You will always find help here on SO.